# Moving an existing GitLab project into a new subgroup

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

Just started out using self hosted GitLab... it looks like it's going to be really useful moving towards a DevOps workflow.

Anyway, after migrating about 20 local Git repositories to the new GitLab server, neatly arranged into 4 groups. I then noticed you can actually have sub-groups within the groups. This would help organisation even further, but I'm struggling to work out how to move the existing projects I've spent a day importing and configuring into a newly created sub-group. Sure I could just create a new project and copy the files over and commit them into the new project, and spend the time reconfiguring the project.

Is there an easy way of moving the existing configured Project from the group into the new subgroup?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Turns out the "slug" for a project... the part of the URL after the GitLab server domain name is made up of the "namespace" and the project name. The name space is the group/subgroup path, so I was looking to transfer project to new namespace.

So for example if the group is "important-group" and project is called "project". Then the slug will be something like /important-group/project. To then move that to /important-group/sub-group/project, we need to create the new subgroup (down arrow next to the "New project" button). Then change the project namespace.

To do this, go to the project page, click the settings button (cog bottom left). Go to the Advanced settings section. And it's just below the rename project option.

**note:** *you need to have "owner" privileges on the project otherwise the settings don't appear... maintainer or developer is not enough.*

[image: Transfer project to new Namespace]

Just select the new subgroup and your done!

Here is the GitLab docs [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/#transferring-an-existing-project-into-another-namespace) with more info on managing projects in GitLab, in case that is useful to anyone.

Comment: At the moment I've made a few moves and emotionally stumbled over the point *`Be careful. Changing the project's namespace can have unintended side effects.`* Apart from the well-documented aspects, are there any things you should definitely watch out for? For example, is there any kind of data loss to be afraid of?

Comment: There shouldn't be any data loss, worst case is you transfer it back to where it came from and everything should still all line up again.

If you change the project URL then any existing git checkouts will need their origin updating with the new URL `git remote get-url origin` to see where a repo's origin is pointed to and `git remote set-url origin <new-url>` to update it.

Also if you have any reporting/scripts/pipelines that have the URL hard coded then they will need updating. Hope that helps :)